# How to select with all columns of a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I want to select using all columns of a dataset without having to enter one by one column names in JAVA like so :

```
dF.select(dF.columns().toString(),"someothercolumn");
```

But it is not working,

Thanks

Comment: try `df.select("*", "other")`?

Comment: Yes, see my own answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like so:

```
dF.select(dF.col("*"),col("someothercolumn"));
```

Thanks.